# Check if parent row has corresponding values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, data-validation

I have a table in an Excel spreadsheet that has **hierarchical rows**:

[image]

> *(Hint: The data below can be copied from the EDIT-view in Stack Exchange and pasted into Excel. This method will result in proper
>   parsing/formatting.)*
>
> ```
> ID    PARENT  UseWith1    UseWith2    UseWith3    UseWith-CheckParent
> 10        WORKORDER   SR      
> 20    10  SR          
> 30    10  WORKORDER   JOBPLAN     
> 40    10  WORKORDER           
> 50    40  WORKORDER   JOBPLAN TOOLITEM
> ```

---

**Question:**

In column F, I want to flag child rows where any of the values in UseWith1,     UseWith2, **or** UseWith3 are missing from the parent row.

**Example:**

[image]

Is there a way to do this in Excel 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [@mikerickson](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/members/mikerickson.73026/) in the [MrExcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/check-if-parent-row-has-corresponding-values.1134602/) community:

> In F3, put the formula:
>
> ```
>  =IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX(C:E,MATCH(B3,A:A,0),0),C3:E3))<>COUNTA(C3:E3), "Missing something", "all there")
> ```
>
> It won't tell you which item is missing from the parent, but it will
>   flag if something is missing from the parent

Answer (score 1):

I am using Excel 2010 so I am not sure if it will work on Excel 2016.

You can try this formula and just edit if needed:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[@[UseWith1]:[UseWith3]]<>""))=3
```

[image]