# Use table column names as range in index array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, range

In an Excel 2016 table:

I have a formula that I use to check if parent records have the right 'Use With' values (if a child record has a 'Use With' value, then it's parents must have it too). More info [here](https://superuser.com/a/1553828/1079908).

> Column B =
>
> `IFERROR(IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX(    C:E,    [@[Parent - RowNum]],0),Table1[@[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]))<>COUNTA(Table1[@[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]), "error", ""),"")`

[image]

---

For example, if I were to delete the value in C2, the formula would successfully flag it as causing an error:

[image]

---

Question:

I'm trying to convert all **explicit cell references** —to— [**structured references**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) (aka table column names). I want to do this to avoid some issues I've been having with adding/deleting columns in the spreadsheet (and because I assume it's best practice/cleaner).

I've tried to replace `C:E` with `Table1[[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]`.

> `=IFERROR(IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX(    Table1[[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]],    [@[Parent - RowNum]],0),Table1[@[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]))<>COUNTA(Table1[@[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]), "error", ""),"")`

However, when I do that, the formula fails to work correctly — it doesn't flag the problem rows with "error".

[image]

---

What's the correct way to use table column names as a range in an index array (instead of using explicit cell references)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add `[#All],` to the index array.

`Table1[[#All],[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]`

Full formula:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX(   Table1[[#All],[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]],    [@[Parent - RowNum]],0),Table1[@[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]))<>COUNTA(Table1[@[Use With 1]:[Use With 3]]), "error", "")`